# Is there an XmlEncode / XmlDecode for .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, encoding

Are there methods for **encoding** and **decoding** **XML** in .NET? I can't seem to find them and am wondering why they aren't there and what to use instead?

I need to encode an XML document and pass it through to a string parameter on a web service. It then needs to be decoded at the other end.

Comment: What do you want these methods to do? Can you give examples of the use of similar methods on some other platform?

Comment: If encoding extra characters is not a problem, you could use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` and `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`. It does encode allot more than is strictly necessary for XML but as long as no 3rd party needs to process the output, it's a quick solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to encoding/decoding of XML names, there is [XmlConvert.EncodeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename.aspx) and [DecodeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.decodename.aspx).

Or are you talking about specifying the encoding/decoding of the whole XML document using [XmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.aspx) or [XDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdeclaration.aspx)? (I thought this took care of [encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdeclaration.encoding.aspx) for us)

Answer (score 9):

Actually with the nice objects in `System.Xml.Linq` you need not worry.

What I mean is you will not get a runtime exception if you run this code.

```
var element = new XElement("Name", "<Node />");
```

The value of the element will be a text node with `&lt;Node /&gt;`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Alex: LINQ to XML and all the other XML APIs in .NET understand when strings need to be escaped and when they do not. In the example above, the value of the element will be a text node with `&lt;Node /&gt;`.

Comment: @John - To put it more eloquently. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing XML as a string parameter (very bad web service design, BTW), then you don't have to do anything. It's up to the web service to do any encoding that may be necessary. Just use `XDocument.ToString()` or whatever and pass the result to the web service.

Comment: @John Saunders: You might want to check out [Passing XML as a parameter to a web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597615/passing-xml-as-a-parameter-to-a-web-service)

Answer (score -1):

It's not true!

```vb
Var element As XElement = <Name><%= GetValue() %></Name>

Private Function GetValue() As String
  Return "Value with < and > as well as a " & Chr(0) & " (Nul)"
End Function
```

does work with lesser and greater than signs but not with special chars like NUL or other low ASCII characters (it does not crash at the time adding the string but when calling ToString() or writing it somewhere).

If readability is not that important, use this method:

```vb
Public Function ToXmlString(ByVal aString As String) As String
    If (aString Is Nothing) Then Return ""
    Dim myResult As New StringBuilder(aString.Length + 10)
    For Each myChar As Char In aString
        If ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.:,;!?-_$£{}()[]+*/\0123456789".IndexOf(myChar) > -1) Then
            myResult.Append(myChar)
        Else
            Select Case myChar
                Case "&"c
                    myResult.Append("&amp;")
                Case """"c
                    myResult.Append("&quot;")
                Case "<"c
                    myResult.Append("&lt;")
                Case ">"c
                    myResult.Append("&gt;")
                Case Else
                    myResult.Append("&#")
                    myResult.Append(AscW(myChar))
                    myResult.Append(";"c)
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    Return myResult.ToString()
End Function
```

to escape the values before you assign them.

If readability is important, implement all constants from 
http://de.selfhtml.org/html/referenz/zeichen.htm.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on what exactly is not true?