# RegEx to remove Hexdecimal charecters from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

There are some hexadecimal values hidden in some of my DB values that are causing me some trouble, does anyone have a RegEx to clean these out?

Here is the error i am getting:

```
'', hexadecimal value 0x19, is an invalid character.
```

This post explains my problem completely but I am looking for a RegEx solution:
http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/

Comment: It's issues like this that make me distrust xml as a general purpose data encoding format.  You can't just dump the value as is into an xml document.  :-(

Comment: @agent-j: XML can encode any character values just fine, via entities.  Although you're right that you can't just dump the data between xml tags and expect the result to be well-formed, but this is no different conceptually from SQL injection attacks that have been around for decades.

Comment: @leppie - I will never need the Hexidecimal infor= - it shouldn't be there.

@BrunoLM - you can't see the values that is the problem, they sneak in copy and pasted from some legacy systems or random word like software.

Comment: @Slee, you can't "see" them? These are some magical quantum hex values? ;-)

Comment: @Ben Voight: as long as you define "any character values" as only Unicode characters (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) and don't assume arbitrary values can be encoded; `<value>&#x0001;</value>` is not legal XML.

Comment: @Slee, feel free to define "hexadecimal values" please. Do you just mean any string that could be interpreted as hex? Eg `ABBA3000DEADBEEF`?

Comment: @Slee: I could, but it would also any occurence of dead, beef, bee, be, b, the dea in dear, any decimal digit, any a, b, c, d, e.

Comment: @Slee: I oul, ut it woul lso ny ourn o , , , , , th  in r, ny iml gt, ny , , , ,

Comment: @Qtax: Apparently he's talking about non-printable characters.

Comment: thanks for the down vote, thought it was a straight forward question - never ran into this before and obviously I am not an expert on the topic hence the need to ask questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of building XML strings by concatenation, you should use the XML handling classes provided with .NET.  These will properly encode dangerous characters as XML entities and produce well-formed XML.

Also, regular expressions don't do well for XML processing.

Comment: The following link has some excellent information on .NET facilities for XML string encoding / decoding.  I've used them to great success:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597056/is-there-an-xmlencode-xmldecode-for-net

Comment: The values that are going to be converted to XML have Hexadecimal values in them that I will never need in any circumstance.  I am not concatenating to build XML but rather trying to clean up my objects before they are converted.

Comment: @Slee: I don't think you are using "hexadecimal" correctly.  Are you wanting to remove control characters, such as carriage return and linefeed, or extended (non-ASCII) characters, such as letters with umlauts and accents?

Comment: this is the error I am getting: '', hexadecimal value 0x19, is an invalid character.

Comment: implementing this code gets rid of my problem but I am guessing a regex solution would be much faster than this: http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/hexadecimal-value-0-is-an-invalid-character/

Comment: @Slee: Ok.  Yes, those are *control characters*.  The slowness of that code is from all the stream junk.  Try `List<char>.RemoveAll` instead, it should be faster even than regex.

Answer (score 0):

I could, but it would also any occurence of dead, beef, bee, be, b, the dea in dear, any decimal digit, any a, b, c, d, e

...

`I oul, ut it woul lso ny ourn o , , , , , th in r, ny iml gt, ny , , , ,`

...

See?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like....

```
    Regex regex = new Regex("0x\\d\\d");

    String Input = "this0x34is my 0x45 test 0x11";

    string Result = regex.Replace(Input, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you're hoping for Regex, but have you tried `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape`? 
I believe this method is specifically intended for your use case.